# jQuery: changing on mark checkbox

Tags: jquery

When you mark/unmark the checkbox I want it to window.location = index.php?mark=1 if it's marked, and if you click and it gets unmarked it should be mark=0

Comment: Can you specify your question a little better? Have you tried something and it doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('input:checkbox').click(function(){
  window.location='/index.php?mark=' + ($(this).attr('checked') ? 1 : 0);
});
```

Should do the trick, but note that means it's going to cause a page reload between checks.

**EDIT** or as [William](https://stackoverflow.com/users/145025/william) mentioned, you can bind to [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) as well.

**EDITv2** Working example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/T5CaC/

Comment: This is correct as long as the only method of changing the checkbox is by the user clicking. If you plan on changing the checkbox programmatically and still want to execute the event, then change click() to change().

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [jQuery.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/). When the checkbox check if the checkbox is checked or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#someCheckbox').change(function() {
    window.location.search = ("?mark=" + (+this.checked));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$('input#mycheckbox').change(function () {
    if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
        window.location = index.php?mark=1; 
        return;
    }
    window.location = index.php?mark=0;
});
```

[**Check Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Axuvk/)